# 'Is' or 'Are' following 'aesthetics'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Aesthetics **are** also very important to the roof of a house.
> 2. Aesthetics **is** also very important to the roof of a house.

Is aesthecics plural? And which one is right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes **aesthetics** refers to the area of philosophical inquiry, and then it is singular, and at other times the word refers to the stylistic features of something that has been fabricated and their effects on those who behold them, and then it is plural.

> The aesthetics of the new office, with its harsh contrasting colors, were rather jarring.
>
> Marxist aesthetics is her area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context and we'd need more information. Aesthetics as a singular subject, name or definition would use "is" but that would be an uncommon scenario.

In the majority of cases, and in the way I understand your sentence, "aesthetics are" would be the correct usage.

Comment: More information is added.

Comment: In this example, definitely option 1.  Option 2 would only be applicable in extreme edge cases, where Aesthetics is used as noun, title - e.g. "Aesthetics" is also very important as a literary work.  Option 1 is far, far more common in everyday usage.